# NameError: name 'num' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

```
def multiply(num):
    (num1 * num2)
    num1 = random.randint(1,12)
    num2 = random.randint(1,12) 
    if maths == "Multiplication" or "m" or "x": 
        ans = int(input("What is the answer to " + str(num1) + " x " + str(num2) + " ? "))
    if ans == multiply(num1, num2):
        print("You are correct! ")
    else:
        print("Wrong, please try again. ")
    return num1 * num2

name = input("What is your name? ")
maths = input("What mathematics would you like to learn, " + name + "? ")
if maths == "Multiplication" or "m" or "x":
    multiply(num)
```

This line of code keeps on coming up with this error, and I'm not sure why:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "program.py", line 15, in <module>
    multiply(num) 
NameError: name 'num' is not defined
```

Is there a way that I can fix this?

Comment: Please fix your indention. This is not valid Python code. It will not produce the error you give because it will not even run.

Comment: Why is your `multiply` function defined to take an argument of `num` that it never uses? Why does it have `(num1 * num2)` under its `def` line? Why are you calling  `multiply` inside itself, and why do you call it with 2 arguments when it's defined to take one argument?

Comment: It seems to me, that **maths** should be the parameter to multiply instead of **num**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`num` is not actually used in `multiply()` so there is no reason to pass it in. Instead, declare `multiply()` without the argument:

```
def multiply():
    '''(num1 * num2)'''
    .
    .
```

And call it from `__main__` like this:

```
if maths == "Multiplication" or "m" or "x":
    multiply()
```

There seems no point in checking within `multiply()` whether it is supposed to perform multiplication as does this line:

```
if maths == "Multiplication" or "m" or "x":
```

And you try to call `multiply()` recursively, which will fail:

```
if ans == multiply(num1, num2):
```

... just use the `*` operator.

Finally, why return the result of the multiplication? What use is the product if the multiplicands are not known outside of function `multiply()`? It might be better to return whether the user got the correct answer.

Putting all of the above together, you get this:

```
import random

def multiply():
    '''(num1 * num2)'''
    num1 = random.randint(1,12)
    num2 = random.randint(1,12)
    ans = int(input("What is the answer to " + str(num1) + " x " + str(num2) + " ? "))
    correct = (ans == num1 * num2)
    if correct:
        print("You are correct! ")
    else:
        print("Wrong, please try again. ")
    return correct

if __name__ == '__main__':
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    maths = input("What mathematics would you like to learn, " + name + "? ")
    if maths == "Multiplication" or "m" or "x":
        correct = multiply()
```